# Count multiple data in 1 column and add them up

Tags: sql

im trying to find out how to count more than 2 data in 1 column and add them up.

currently i have this code

```
SELECT COUNT(Month) as [Winter]
FROM SalesData
Where Month = 'January' + 'February' + 'March';
```

Im trying to count how many January, February and March are on the column and total them but I don't know what im missing. if someone could shed some light. thank you very much

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but look up the `IN` operator - it might be what you're after

Comment: You haven't specified your DBMS, but I guess you get zero results, since `'January' + 'February' + 'March'` presumably equals `'JanuaryFebruaryMarch'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this wrong :

```
'January' + 'February' + 'March'
```

This is concatenating values, it won't check if Month is equal to one of these. You need to use `IN` operator instead.

```
select count(month) as 'Winter'
from salesdata
where month in ('January', 'February', 'March');
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info guys, was using MS access. Thank you Jean, that did the trick. Did not know about the 'in' operator.